# How to both center and widen both epigraph text & source?

Tags: xetex, scrbook, epigraphs

I would like to both center and widen an epigraph, including its source.  So I did something like:

```
\documentclass {scrbook}

\usepackage {epigraph}

\setlength \epigraphwidth {\textwidth}
\setlength \epigraphrule {0pt}
\renewcommand {\epigraphflush} {center}
\renewcommand {\sourceflush} {center}

\begin {document}
\chapter {Chapter}
\epigraph {A somewhat long epigraph should be here.}  {— Name}

This paragraph text should fill at least a whole line to give a better
idea of what I am doing here.

\end {document}
```

But while I do get the source centered, the text gets left aligned.  What gives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually `\renewcommand {\epigraphflush} {center}` centres the minipage which contains the epigraph, but within this minipage, the epigraph remains justified. So if the epigraph width is text width, you'll see nothing, except if you  add a `\centering command`:

```
\documentclass {book}

\usepackage {epigraph}

\setlength \epigraphwidth {\linewidth}
\setlength \epigraphrule {0pt}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand {\epigraphflush}{center}}
\renewcommand {\sourceflush} {center}

\begin {document}

\chapter {Chapter}
\epigraph {\centering A somewhat long epigraph should be here.} {— Name}

This paragraph text should fill at least a whole line to give a better
idea of what I am doing here.

\end {document}
```

[image]